# python selenium click file upload options

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload

How can I click file upload page options with python selenium? I mean, I click this `<input type="file" id="uploadfile">` with this code: `driver.find_element_by_id("uploadfile").click()` 
then, a small window opens, this window's title is 'File Upload' and I want write on location input in this window. How can I do this? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file upload option is an `input` tag and its type is `file` then you can directly upload the file using `send_keys()` method in Selenium

e.g.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("uploadfile").send_keys("D:\test\filename.extension")
```

Note :enter absolute location of your file